# How can I fetch a subsequent set of results from couchdb, like I would with SQL's "next N rows"?

Tags: asp.net, sql, couchdb

I am using couchdb and ASP.NET for my application. I have a large set of data which will spoil my performance if I load it fully on page load, so I need to do it like a "river view".

If I scroll down my ajax call should fetch the next set of 12 results to view in my page. This is possible in SQL whereas I need to do it in couch db. I Googled it but i could find no results.

Here's code in C# and SQL; I need to do the same thing in couchdb.

```
public string GetData()
{
RecordCount = RecordCount + 10;
string Sql = "SELECT Title, DateCreated, Slug FROM be_Posts ORDER BY Title OFFSET " + FirstCount + " ROWS FETCH NEXT 10 ROWS ONLY";
FirstCount = RecordCount;
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
dt = new DataTable();
da = new SqlCeDataAdapter(Sql, con);
con.Open();
da.Fill(dt);
DataView dv = dt.DefaultView;
foreach (DataRowView row in dv)
{
sb.AppendFormat("<p>Post Title" + " <strong>" + row["Title"] + "</strong>");
sb.AppendFormat("<p>Post Date" + " <strong>" + row["DateCreated"] + "</strong>");
sb.AppendFormat("<p>Slug" + " <strong>" + row["Slug"] + "</strong>");
sb.AppendFormat("<hr/>");
}
sb.AppendFormat("<divstyle='height:15px;'></div>");
con.Close();
return sb.ToString();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use STARTKEY, ENDKEY and LIMIT URL query arguments for GET of the view with results, to yield similar effect.

[Docs on query parameters](http://wiki.apache.org/couchdb/HTTP_view_API#Querying_Options)

Comment: Ya can u pls give a simple example how to do it... because i could't any working example for this.... i am screwed up with this..

Answer (score 0):

I think you should look at this recipe: http://guide.couchdb.org/draft/recipes.html#pagination

If you have a small set of data, using 'limit' and 'skip' is fine, otherwise it is very slow because cocuhdb retrieves the whole set of documents internally anyway and just skips the first pages.

The trick is to use 'startkey' and 'endkey' and always retrieve N+1 documents. This means that you use the first N documents in your view and use the document N+1 with 'next_startkey_docid' as the start key of your next page.

If you need full pagination, you can implement goto first page, goto last page and goto next/previous page with the last strategy and also using 'descending' when appropriate to reverse the order of your sesarch. You can't implement goto an arbitrary page though. To implement a jump to an arbitrary page, you have to internally skip all the intermediate pages.